# Webview save password rotation issue

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have my `WebView` inside a `DialogFragment` showing a login page, after the user has introduced the username and password, is prompted to save his password, but if the user rotate the phone in that moment, the `WebView` will crash, the prompt will be hidden to the user, and thereby unable to reenter/rewrite data, being the `WebView` disabled in those functionality, and in this particular case where the `DialogFragment` survives the configuration changes, the user won't be able to submit the data, even if I change configuration again, and another problem, is that the internal OS doesn't recover anymore until I reconstruct everything, in example, I leave the `WebView` and when I recreate it the keyboard isn't showed up until the configuration changes again.

The crash log is the following:

```
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235): Activity com.example.twitterlibraryservice.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45aef418 that was originally added here
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.twitterlibraryservice.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45aef418 that was originally added here
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:255)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.webkit.WebView.onSavePassword(WebView.java:1065)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:431)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-24 08:36:21.694: E/WindowManager(21235):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT
Corrected the `WebView` keyboard issue asking for the focus after it is created.

```
mWebView.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your Activiy doesn't handle orientation changes. Therefore, Android OS is killing your Activity and creating a new one with the new orientation.

You could try to call the `dimiss` method of your DialogFragment in the `onPause` of your Activity.

That will probably fix your leak, but the behavior will probably not be what you're expecting.